# How to convert byte array to base64 String

Tags: java

```
List<Map<String, Object>> lists = baseDao.getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(queryForImages, productId);
        **System.out.println("size----" + lists.size());**
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Map<String, Object> base64 : lists) {
            byte[] imgData = (byte[]) base64.get("images");
            String base64Encoded = new String(imgData, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            // byte[] encodedImage = Base64.encodeBase64(imgData);
            System.out.println("encoded---2" + base64Encoded);
        }
```

i retrieve list of images from db and convert byte array to base64 string ,if i sysout only the last image in the list prints in sysout , even sysout list.size under the method is not printing .

Comment: Is there any exception and where does the code stuck?

Comment: Another option to convert byte array to base64 string is Base64.encode(imgData )

Comment: hello kevin , i dont get any exception , from db i get list of images ,if i sysout only the last image in the list prints ,and why sysout (lists.size()); is not printing , the only thing i get is last image gets converted to base64 , i need to all images in the list .

Comment: please watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t7g06nzlkjo

Answer (score 13):

To start with, this is wrong:

```
String base64Encoded = new String(imgData, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

The image bytes you have do not represent UTF-8 encoded text, so it makes no sense to create a `String` out of the bytes, pretending that this is UTF-8 encoded text.

If you are using Java 8, then use the [`Base64`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) class available in the standard library:

```
import java.util.Base64;

// ...

byte[] imgData = (byte[]) base64.get("images");

String base64Encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(imgData);
```

If you are not using Java 8, you can use a third-party library, for example [Apache Commons Codec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/), which includes classes for Base64 encoding and decoding.

Comment: i use java 1.7 , Base64.getEncoder() this method is not available in import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 please tell me what is jar needed .

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t7g06nzlkjo  , please watch this videos because still i have problem

Answer (score 13):

In android, you can use Base64 (android.util.Base64) to encoded byte[] to String;

```
String encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

and

Decoding part as like following;

```
byte[] byteArray = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(encodedString);
```

Usually this technique used in android app to send binary file/data to Server, using Web Service;

Answer (score 4):

If you are working with Android you can use the following code by importing the Android version of the [Base64 class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html#encode(byte[],%20int)):

```
Base64.encodeToString(payload, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

From Android API 26, you can use java.util.Base64 as well.

Answer (score 3):

Prior to java 1.8  use [apache commons library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/)

```
String base64 = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(imgData))
```